# Search numpy array ((x, y, z)...) for z matching nearest x, y

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a very large array similar to elevation data of the format:

```
triplets = ((x0, y0, z0), 
            (x1, y1, z1), 
            ... ,
            (xn, yn, zn))
```

where x, y, z are all floats in metres. You can create suitable test data matching this format with:

```
x = np.arange(20, 40, dtype=np.float64)
y = np.arange(30, 50, dtype=np.float64)
z = np.random.random(20) * 25.0
triplets = np.hstack((x, y, z)).reshape((len(x),3))
```

I want to be able to efficiently find the corresponding z-value for a given (x,y) pair. My research so far leads to more questions. Here's what I've got:

1. Iterate through all of the triplets:

   ```
   query = (a, b) # where a, b are the x and y coordinates we're looking for
   for i in triplets:
     if i[0] == query[0] and i[1] == query[1]:
       result = i[2]
   ```

   Drawbacks: slow; `a, b` must exist, which is a problem with comparing floats.
2. Use [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) to find nearest:

   ```
   points = triplets[:,0:2] # drops the z column
   tree = cKDTree(points)
   idx = tree.query((a, b))[1] # this returns a tuple, we want the index
   query = tree.data[idx]
   result = triplets[idx, 2]
   ```

   Drawbacks: returns nearest point rather than interpolating.
3. Using [`interp2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) as per comment:

   ```
   f = interp2d(x, y, z)
   result = f(a, b)
   ```

   Drawbacks: doesn't work on a large dataset. I get `OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate` when run on real data.  (My real data is some 11 million points.)

So the question is: is there any straightforward way of doing this that I'm overlooking? Are there ways to reduce the drawbacks of the above?

Comment: Would it be feasible to create a dictionary with tuples of the form `(x, y)` as the keys, mapping to `z` values? That would make lookups constant time, with a large upfront cost of generating the dictionary, and possibly a nasty hit to memory usage.

Comment: Do you need this? [scipy.interpolate.interp2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d)

Comment: Only if you know your keys in advance. Say your input data has a (20.05, 45.0, 5.55). We assign it into the dict with `foo[(20.05, 45.0)] = 5.55`. When you try to query your dict `foo[(20, 45)]`, you would get a `KeyError`. What I'm looking for is it to return the value of the nearest point, or, even better, an interpolated value derived from nearby points.

Comment: You have, as you say, triplets of data. Would it be possible to represent them as three 2D fields using something like [scipy.interpolate.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) and then do a 2d interpolation? (this would probably only work well if your z-values are pretty smooth)

Comment: For large sets of data I doubt anything will beat cKDTree.

Comment: @ThomChubb My real data triplets were generated through gridding unevenly spaced data. Our best-practices here require I use minimum curvature (or cubic spline) to fill in the gaps. This question is really about sampling my grid at arbitrary points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to interpolate the result, rather than just find the z value for the nearest neighbour, I would consider doing something like the following:

1. Use a k-d tree to partition your data points according to their *(x, y)* coordinates
2. For a given *(xi, yi)* point to interpolate, find its *k* nearest neighbours
3. Take the average of their *z* values, weighted according to their distance from *(xi, yi)*

The code might look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# some fake (x, y, z) data
XY = np.random.rand(10000, 2) - 0.5
Z = np.exp(-((XY ** 2).sum(1) / 0.1) ** 2)

# construct a k-d tree from the (x, y) coordinates
tree = cKDTree(XY)

# a random point to query
xy = np.random.rand(2) - 0.5

# find the k nearest neighbours (say, k=3)
distances, indices = tree.query(xy, k=3)

# the z-values for the k nearest neighbours of xy
z_vals = Z[indices]

# take the average of these z-values, weighted by 1 / distance from xy
dw_avg = np.average(z_vals, weights=(1. / distances))
```

It's worth playing around a bit with the value of *k*, the number of nearest neighbours to take the average of. This is essentially a crude form of [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), where the value of *k* controls the degree of 'smoothness' you're imposing on the underlying distribution of z-values. A larger *k* results in more smoothness.

Similarly, you might want to play around with how you weight the contributions of points according to their distance from *(xi, yi)*, depending on how you think similarity in *z* decreases with increasing *x, y* distance. For example you might want to weight by `(1 / distances ** 2)` rather than `(1 / distances)`.

In terms of performance, [constructing and searching k-d trees are both very efficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Complexity). Bear in mind that you only need to construct the tree once for your dataset, and if necessary you can query multiple points at a time by passing *(N, 2)* arrays to `tree.query()`.

Tools for approximate nearest neighbour searches, such as [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/), might potentially be quicker, but these are usually more helpful in situations when the dimensionality of your data is very high.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your cKDTree code, you got the `idx`, why do the for loop again? You can get the result just by `result = triplets[idx, 2]`.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

x = np.arange(20, 40, dtype=np.float64)
y = np.arange(30, 50, dtype=np.float64)
z = np.random.random(20) * 25.0
triplets = np.hstack((x, y, z)).reshape((len(x),3))

a = 30.1
b = 40.5

points = triplets[:,0:2] # drops the z column
tree = cKDTree(points)
idx = tree.query((a, b))[1] # this returns a tuple, we want the index
result = triplets[idx, 2]
```

Comment: My mistake when entering the question. I've updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sparse matrix and use simple indexing.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.arange(20, 40, dtype=np.float64)
In [3]: y = np.arange(30, 50, dtype=np.float64)
In [4]: z = np.random.random(20) * 25.0
In [9]: from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
In [12]: m = coo_matrix((z, (x, y))).tolil()
In [17]: m[25,35]
Out[17]: 17.410532044604292
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however, it doesn't work reliably! I ran the code you provided, and for some values, it returns the expected results. For others it returns 0. Eg. For `m[25,35]` it works, as does `m[25.1, 35.999]`. But, for `m[25,36]` I get nothing.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in float values. So you can create indexes for x and y values. For example, you can create matrix m from arrays xi, yi and z. The xi and yi are vectors of positions of items in x and y. You can create a dict to convert values from x to xi, or presort x and then use some type of binary search to find the index of item.